# What is the correct way of specifying SOAP request payload for Spring WebServiceTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl

I'm a little stuck. I have a WSDL that I have used to generate Java stubs from (using the maven-jaxb2-plugin). It has generated the objects for Response, however it has not generated me an object for the Request. Looking at the WSDL I'm guessing it is because the Request is 'simple'

extract:

```
<message name='getImagesRequest'>
 <part name='Type' type='xsd:string'/>
 <part name='Code' type='xsd:string'/>    
</message>
```

I am trying to do:

```
    String request = "<Type>" + inKey.getType() + "</Type>" +                         
                     "<Code>" + inKey.getCode() + "</Code>";

    StreamSource requestPayload = new StreamSource(new StringReader(request));

    WebServiceMessageCallback requestCallback = new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
        @Override
        public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage inMessage) throws IOException, TransformerException
        {
            ((SoapMessage) inMessage).setSoapAction("/getImagesRequest");
        }
    };

    SourceExtractor<SupplierList> responseExtractor = new SourceExtractor<SupplierList>() {
        @Override
        public SupplierList extractData(Source inSource) throws IOException, TransformerException
        {
            return (SupplierList) (getWebServiceTemplate().getUnmarshaller().unmarshal(inSource));
        }
    };

    SupplierList response = (SupplierList) getWebServiceTemplate().sendSourceAndReceive(requestPayload, requestCallback, responseExtractor);
```

However, it is all failing with a rather unhelpful error of "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed."

Can someone point me into the right direction of setting the payload correctly as I have a feeling I'm way off the mark.

Thanks!

Comment: The jaxb2 plugin doesn't use your wsdl it uses the xsd's only so if your type isn't in there it will not generate anything. You might want to try the jax-ws plugin to generate objects.

Comment: Really? Even with <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>? Thanks, I will give jax-ws a go!

Comment: not AFAIK. But maybe things have changed...

Comment: @M.Deinum: Looks like you should be able to do what I am doing http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/. However you are right, there is a good chance what is happening is only my xsd is getting picked up and not my wsdl. Thanks :)